# change header in putty log file

Tags: windows, putty

When I enable logging in putty, I get a header in the log file that looks as follows.

=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2015.04.06 11:51:09 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=

I want it to look as follows.

2015.04.06 11:51:09

Is there a way to configure the format of the header line inserted into a putty log? I have looked through the online docs and found nothing.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same aim as you when trying to display CSV data using Live Graph - the auto header would mess up the first columns which are used to label each graph.

My workaround was to "pre label" a CSV file with "header1, header2, header3" etc. and then tell putty to append to this file - therefore the Putty auto message will still appear but wont mess up any program that relies on reading the first column to work!